# Tensorflow filter operation on dataset with several columns

Tags: tensorflow, filter

I want to create a subset of my data by applying tf.data.Dataset filter operation. I have this data:

```
data = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 12], [1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9, 12]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data)
```

I want to retrieve a subset of 'dataset' which corresponds to all elements whose first column is equal to 1. So, result should be:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 3, 8]] # dtype : dataset
```

I tried this:

```
subset = dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.equal(x[0], 1))
```

But I don't get the correct result, since it sends me back x[0]
Someone to help me ?

Comment: Both elements in your dataset *do* start with 1...

Comment: @NicolasGervais I'm not sure I understand. I have however updated the post to show the result I expect. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved it:

```
a = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 9, 12])
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 9, 12])
data_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((a, b))
subset = data_set.filter(lambda x, y: tf.equal(x, 1))
```